# Using CDK Overlay as a Popover when you Mouse Enter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mouseover, angular-cdk-overlay

How can this be updated to use Angular 14 or higher. It seems like there should be an easier approach for this:(https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-overlay-with-mouseover-vuc8ip?file=app%2Fpopup%2Fpopup.component.ts)